# Can't match any admin routes in Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-module

I have 3 modules: App, Shared, Core and Admin
This is the root object:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'home', component:HomeComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuardService]},
  {path:'detail/:id', component:DetailComponent},
  {path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent},
  {path:'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path:'', redirectTo:'login', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path:'**', pathMatch: 'full' ,redirectTo:'login'}

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Core Module, where are all the main components declared, so this is like my main module and im importing the appRoutingModule here:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomeComponent, 
    DetailComponent, 
    RegisterComponent, 
    LoginComponent, 
    NavbarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AdminModule    

  ],
  exports:[AppRoutingModule, NavbarComponent]
})
export class CoreModule {
//para evitar que este modulo seja importado mais que uma vez
  constructor( @Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: CoreModule) {
    if (parentModule) {
      throw new Error('CoreModule has already been loaded. You should only import Core modules in the AppModule only.');
    }
  }
}
```

The app.Module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    SharedModule,
    CoreModule,
    AdminModule
  ],
  providers: [
    DataService, 
    fakeBackendProvider, 
    AuthService, 
    AuthGuardService, 
    ShoppingCartService 
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And finally, the admin module and it's routing file

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    AdminRoutingModule
    RouterModule.forChild([])
    ],
    declarations: [AdminComponent],

  exports:[AdminComponent],
  providers:[AuthGuardService]
})
export class AdminModule { }
```

This is the configuration file of the admin routes:

```
export const adminRoutes: Routes = [
  {path:'admin', component:AdminComponent , canActivate:[AuthGuardService] },


];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(adminRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AdminRoutingModule { }
```

I've tried everything I could imagine, importing, exporting, declaring...nothing works. When I click in the Admin link (when logged in), the system doesn't recognize the routes, so it gives me the login because thats the so called wild card...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He had some modules in shared module which were causing duplicate imports,

Like HttpClientModule, AdminModule, etc.

Imports were messed up. Once imports were in right place. It was cool and moved Admin module as a lazy loaded module.

And i implemented the same explained by Gérôme Grignon on his project. And it worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

Using `RouterModule.forChild()` tells your AdminModule how it'll deal with routing for its components but you need to communicate with the parent router, `RouterModule.forRoot()` declared in AppModule here.

Declare the main route for the admin feature of your app inside the *routes* array of your AppRoutingModule ( 'loadChildren' will allow you to enable lazy loading on the AdminModule) :

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'home', component:HomeComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuardService]},
  {path:'detail/:id', component:DetailComponent},
  {path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent},
  {path:'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'admin', loadChildren: () => import('./admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule)},
  {path:'', redirectTo:'login', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path:'**', pathMatch: 'full' ,redirectTo:'login'}

];
```

Update your adminRoutes to an empty path as the 'admin' segment is declared inside the AppRoutingModule route (as you don't want to route to admin/admin) :

```
export const adminRoutes: Routes = [
  {path:'', component:AdminComponent , canActivate:[AuthGuardService] },
];
```

And remove `RouterModule.forChild([])` from the *imports* array of your AdminModule.

Comment: as Aakash said, this answer is correct, but i have to accept Aakash's because he showed me the same way plus saw other issues. Thank you both!